# Group of checkbox always return empty values

Tags: laravel, validation, checkbox, laravel-blade

i have a strange problem with laravel and checkbox.

I have a group of checkbox and I'm not able to have value to save on database.

My migration:

```
$table->json('send_reminder')->nullable();
```

My model:

```
protected $fillable = [
  .....
    'send_reminder',
  ....
];
```

my index.php

class Index extends Component{
public
....
$send_reminder,
....

My form index.blade.php

```
<div class="input-group input-group-static my-3">
      <div class="form-control @error('reminder') is-invalid @enderror">
            Notification interval: <br>                                             
         @foreach(\App\Enums\ReminderInterval::options() as $option => $reminder)
          <label>
             <input name="send_reminder[]" value="{{(str_replace('_','',$option))}}"
                    type="checkbox">
                    {{(str_replace('_',' ',$option))}}
          </label><br>
        @endforeach
</div>
```

When I try to save data to variable and DD the data, the field is always null.

```
$data = [
      ....other data...
      'send_reminder' => $this->send_reminder
      ];
      dd($data);
```

Can you help me?
thanks!

---- complete code of function path: app/Http/Livewire/User/Dashboard/Deadlines/Add/Index.php

```
    public function Add(){
        $msg = [
            'check_reminder' => 'Select Reminder',
            'check_reminder.in' => 'Select Reminder',
            'note.required' => 'Please add a public note.',
        ];
        $validated = $this->validate([
            'customer_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'date' => 'required|date',
            'amount' => array('required','regex:/^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)*$/'),
        ], $msg);

        // max customers with current subscription
        $customer_of_user = count(DB::table("customers")->where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get());
        $allowed_customers = Admin::ProductAllowedCustomers($this->active_subscription->name);

        if (!$allowed_customers) {
            $this->allowed_deadlines = "unlimited";
        }

        try {
            //MAX Deadlines created about this user
            $deadline_of_customer = DB::table('deadlines')
                ->where('customer_id', $validated['customer_id'])
                ->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
                ->get();
            $deadline_of_customer = count($deadline_of_customer);
            //Allowed Deadlines
            $allowed_deadlines = Admin::ProductAllowedDeadlines($this->active_subscription->name);
            //If allowed customers are unlimited
            if ($this->allowed_deadlines == "unlimited" OR $deadline_of_customer < $allowed_deadlines) {


                $data = [
                    'subscription_id' => $this->active_subscription->id,
                    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                    'slug' => strtoupper(Str::random(20)),
                    'renew_state' => $this->renew_state,
                    'type_of_renew' => $this->type_of_renew,
                    'send_reminder' => $this->send_reminder
                ];
                dd($data);

                //Create Deadline
                Deadline::create(array_merge($data, $validated));

                //Get Reminder Values
//                switch($this->reminder) {
//                    case('1_day_before'):$this->reminder = 1; break;
//                    case('7_days_before'):$this->reminder = 7; break;
//                    case('30_days_before'):$this->reminder = 30; break;
//                    case('60_days_before'):$this->reminder = 60; break;
//                    default: $this->reminder = 0;
//                }

                //Send Email
                /*if($this->reminder):
                    dispatch(function () {
                    //Get Renew State Values
                    switch ($this->renew_state){
                        case($this->renew_state == "to_renew"): $this->renew_state = "To Renew"; break;
                        case($this->renew_state == "waiting_cash"): $this->renew_state = "Waiting for Cash"; break;
                        case($this->renew_state == "renewed"): $this->renew_state = "Renewed"; break;
                        default:$this->renew_state = "Deleted";
                    }
                    //Get Type of Renew Values
                    switch ($this->type_of_renew){
                        case($this->type_of_renew == "domain"): $this->type_of_renew = "Domain"; break;
                        case($this->type_of_renew == "hosting"): $this->type_of_renew = "Hosting"; break;
                        case($this->type_of_renew == "privacy_cookie"): $this->type_of_renew = "Privacy Cookie"; break;
                        default:$this->type_of_renew = "Other";
                    }

                    //Find Customer
                    $customer = Customer::find($this->customer_id);
                    //Data to send
                    $data = [
                        'name' => $customer->name,
                        'type_of_renew' => $this->type_of_renew,
                        'renew_state' => $this->renew_state,
                        'date' => date('d-M-Y'),
                        'note' => $this->note,
                        'amount' => $this->amount . ' ' . strtoupper(Admin::Currency()),
                    ];

                    //Mail To
                    Mail::to($customer->email)->send(new Reminder($data,Auth::user()->id));
                    //Delay
                })->delay(now()->addDays($this->reminder));
                endif;*/

                session()->flash('success', 'Added Successfully');
                return redirect(route('UserDeadlines'));
            }
            else {
                session()->flash('error', 'Your subscription allows you to create only ' . $allowed_deadlines .
                    ' Deadlines for each Customer.Please upgrade your Subscription');
//                return redirect(route('UserDeadlines'));
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return session()->flash('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: ``save data to variable and DD the data`` where? In your controller? Can you post the complete code of the method from the controller?

Comment: @OMiShah I added all the function to add data to DB. I'm using livewire.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the rest of your code, if you posted it all you would be able to get more help. That being said, livewire will not just look for inputs on your page, you need to let it know by using `wire:model="send_reminder"`:

Working example: [Example](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/fd0c8976-8ede-4fce-bdd0-0853e3e2d037)

`test-field.blade.php`

```php
<div>
    <input wire:model="send_reminder" name="send_reminder[]" value="1" type="checkbox">
    <input wire:model="send_reminder" name="send_reminder[]" value="2" type="checkbox">
    <input wire:model="send_reminder" name="send_reminder[]" value="3" type="checkbox">
    <input wire:model="send_reminder" name="send_reminder[]" value="4" type="checkbox">

    <div>{{ print_r($send_reminder) }}</div>
</div>
```

TestField.php

```php
class TestField extends Component
{
    public $send_reminder = array();

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test-field');
    }
}
```